# How can I write responsive CSS for multiple generated items in a grid layout?

Tags: html, css, responsive, css-grid

I am working on a web application that generates a grid layout from some textboxes. My problem is I cannot generate responsive code on the fly and am forced to use one stylesheet for loading responsive code.

Now while I am new to CSS and grid, I have been able to create grid successfully using this code:

```css
/* grid layout */

.lt-grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

.lt-1 { grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 3; }

.lt-2 { grid-area: 2 / 1 / 3 / 3; }

.lt-3 { grid-area: 3 / 2 / 5 / 3; }

.lt-4 { grid-area: 3 / 1 / 4 / 2; }

/* responsive code */

@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .lt-grid-container {
        grid-template-rows: auto;   /*dont change */
        grid-template-columns: 1fr;   /* dont change */
    }

    .lt-1 {
      grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 2;
    }

    .lt-2 {
      grid-area: 2 / 1 / 3 / 2;
    }

    .lt-3 {
      grid-area: 3 / 1 / 4 / 2;
    }

    .lt-4 {
      grid-area: 4 / 1 / 5 / 2;
    }
}
```

```html
<div style="border: 1px solid #4CAF50;color: #000000; background-color: #fff">
    <div style="background-color: #4CAF50; min-height: 30px;">
    </div>
    <div style="justify-self: center; align-self: center;margin: 1.3em; font-size: 1.3em;">Free Download: Best affiliate marketing tools.
    </div>
    <div style="margin: 1.3em;justify-self: center; align-self: center;">
    <a href="#" target="_blank">
    <span > Click Me!</span>
    </a> 
    </div>
</div>
```

so my whole section becomes one single column after another. The problem is that, while first part of my code is generated on the fly, the responsive section is static.

I want same responsive code to be used for all auto-generated CSS code, and will only apply to specific selectors. I expect the same set of responsive code to be used for multiple CSS codes even if class names change.

I don't know how to generate a responsive design using nth-child or something which can be generalized. So I created something like:

```css
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .alldivs {
        grid-template-rows: auto;   /* dont change */
        grid-template-columns: 1fr;   /* dont change */
    }
    .child1 {
      grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 2;
    }

    .child2 {
      grid-area: 2 / 1 / 3 / 2;
    }
}
```

and from there, I don't know what to do.

Comment: Where you say "I want same responsive code to be used for all auto-generated css code" do you mean generated HTML? Or are you using a CSS pre-processor of some sort? If so, that's very relevant to the question and you should probably add the processor as a tag.

Comment: If you don’t want your CSS applied based on specific class names, then you need to find something else, like for example the relation of elements between each other inside the DOM. But to be able to give any further advise on that, we’d need to see some examples of the HTML structures you want this to apply to.

Comment: @DBS yup generated html.

Comment: @04FS added some html code

Comment: You mean: you are getting HTML and CSS code from external sources and you want to have a CSS code which works for mobile clients that works for every given HTML code?

Comment: @yunzen yup exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .lt-grid-container {
    grid-template-rows: auto;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  }
  .lt-grid-container > * {
    grid-area: auto / 1 / span 1 / span 1;
  }
}
```

The `span 1` values for `grid-row-end` and `grid-column-end` works so that every grid item covers only one vertical and one horizontal track.
The `auto` value for `grid-row-start` will stack them one after the other

Comment: wow that actually worked. I knew someone can generalize that whole thing. Mindful people can generalize these tricky situations. Thanks a ton